# How to import chai-as-promised globally in protractor config file

Tags: typescript

I want to import chai-as-promised library globally into my protractor config file so that I need to not to define chai-as-promised in every test.

I have tried below code in my config file:

```
onPrepare: () => {
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5000);
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
browser.manage().window().maximize();
Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
global.chai = chai;
}
```

But it says, Property 'chai' does not exist on type 'Global'.

Comment: Have you done `npm install @types/chai`?

Comment: yes, i tried that too but still not working